# How can I get the ID of selected order in the list of orders Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I am using Prestashop for an e-comercial web site. I want to export orders into an excel file. For that I added a button into the order by adding these lines

```
{block name=preTable}
<div><button type="button">Exporter Excel!</button>
<button type="button">Exporter PDF </button></div>
{/block}
```

into the file *\admin\themes\default\template\controllers\orders\helpers\list*. To execute the necessary query I need to have the *id* of the selected orders, but I really don't know how I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Prestashop 1.6 version.

You don't need any modifications. You can filter the orders you want to export (by date or other parameters) with *Search* and then press the *Export* button.

[image: Orders list]

Comment: i don't want to use the normal export, i insist to add a button because i need to export it as pdf, XML and excel so i need three buttons.

Comment: So now you have a clue where to add your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes with the name "orderBox[]" contain ID value of the order. Every row that is selected will have row ID in array orderBox. So in your post method you access it through:

```
$orders = Tools::getValue('orderBox[]');
foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
// do something with ids
}
```

Comment: But wich file can i find that checkBox?